# How can I remove a sprite from an arrayList of sprites and remove it off the screen when a collision happens with the sprite? Java/Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, collision

In my game, i want to be able to collect coins. I have an arrayList of sprites of that coin so that I can draw multiple coins spaced out individually. These coins also move with the background (to emulate a car driving) and i want it so when the coin hits the car, it disappears and is collected. 
Thank you for helping.

Comment: use `ArrayList` function `remove(index)` to remove sprite at specified position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getBoundingRectangle()` method of `Sprite` and check is there and collision with other rectangle and if yes you can remove that coin from coinList.

```
ArrayList<Sprite> coinList;
Sprite car;

@Override
public void create() {

    coinList=new ArrayList<>();
    car=new Sprite();
    coinList.add(new Sprite());
}

@Override
public void render() {

    //Gdx.gl....

    spriteBatch.begin();
    for (Sprite coin:coinList)
        coin.draw(spriteBatch);
    spriteBatch.end();

    for(Sprite coin:coinList)
        if(car.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(coin.getBoundingRectangle())) {
            coinList.remove(coin);
            break;
        }  
}
```

---

**EDIT**

You can use `Iterator` to prevent `ConcurrentModificationException`

```
for (Iterator<Sprite> iterator = coinList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     Sprite coin = iterator.next();
     if (car.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(coin.getBoundingRectangle())) {
        // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
        iterator.remove();
     }
}
```

You can use `Array` instead of `ArrayList`, there are bunch [classes](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/package-summary.html) inside libGDX that are optimised to avoid garbage collection as much as possible also having many benefits.

You should always try to use libGDX classes whenever you can.

Comment: You better use Iterator to prevent ConcurrentModificationException in the future, also there is Array<T> implemented in libgdx which is the preferred collection over arraylist.